# Setting up proxy for api requests

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, api, request

I'm trying to get data from my back-end. I'm using spring boot and react. When I tried to fetch data I got this error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/getText' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource 
with CORS disabled.
```

So after research I realized that I have to set up my proxy. So I added proxy to my`package.json` file and now it look like this

```
{
 "name": "web-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
 }
}
```

And still I'm getting the same error. This is my back-end and front-end that I use. React method -

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/getText")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

And Spring controller -

```
@RestController
public class TextController {

  @Autowired
  private TextService textService;

   @RequestMapping(path = "/getText", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<?> getAllText(){
      List<String> result = textService.getAllText();
      return new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
   }

}
```

Comment: I found my error the problem was `fetch("http://localhost:8080/getText")` I changed it to `fetch("/getText")` and it seems to work

Comment: It will work for development, but your CORS issue will pop up again once you deploy your code unless you deploy your react code to your spring boot instance.  If you have the option, you might be better off updating the spring boot app to allow CORS for your react app